# APS style bibliography with bibtex in BMC Journal

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am trying to use APS style bibliography with bibtex in a bmc_article template I have from [here](http://www.biomedcentral.com/authors/tex). This is apparently a requirement for [this](http://jes.eurasipjournals.springeropen.com/submission-guidelines/research-article) journal. I can't seem to get the proper citations working properly. So far the closest style is spphys.bst. However, that does not list doi in the "`doi: 10.1111/bjet.12103`" style but instead prints "URL [doi URL here]".  Is there a way to change this? Apart from that I also tried `aps_nameyear.bst` but it does not print the citations in numbered style.

Is there a better style which is more standard than these? Even though I would love to It would take considerable time to make my own `.bst` file.

Comment: Welcome to Tex-SE! You might want to add a little more information, so it is easier for others to help you.
How did you format your bibtex entries? In particular, where did the doi end up in the bibtex entires?
I cannot find a spphys.bst at your link, did you get it somewhere else? 

Last but not least, many journals provide tex templates, does this one not?

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time learning the language in BST file and made my own style file based on bmc-mathphys.bst which is part of the bmc_article package. [Here is the file](http://suchakra.in/stuff/chakra-phys.bst) if anyone needs that. I have not verified line by line  how accurate this is to the style suggested by EURASIP Journal on Embedded Systems, but it looks pretty close to me.